# Update from Mac OS X10.5 to 10.8

Tags: macos, mac

How to upgrade from MAC OS X 10.5 to OS X 10.8 ?

Can I just buy 10.8 as download (can't find in app store now), burn and install ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I just buy 10.8 as download (can't find in app store now), burn
>   and install ?

OS X 10.8 has not been released at this time.  Your ability to upgrade from OS X 10.5 will be based on your own hardware.  Apple released all the upgrade information awhile ago I would go read that.

If this answers your question I would appreciate it if you would accept it.  You have asked 16 questions and most have correct answers.

> Basic System Requirements for OS X Mountain Lion:
>
> - 64-Bit Intel Core 2 Duo processor or better required
> - Ability to boot into OS X 64-bit kernel
> - Advanced GPU chipset required
> - Internet connection required to download and install OS X 10.8

### Macs that are NOT expected to support OS X Mountain Lion

> Older Macs and those with weaker GPU’s will likely be left behind:
>
> - Anything with an Intel GMA 950 or x3100 integrated graphics card
> - Anything with an ATI Radeon X1600
> - MacBook models released prior to 2008
> - Mac Mini released prior to 2007
> - iMac models released prior to 2007
> - Original MacBook Air

### Macs that will support OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion

> - MacBook Pro – 13″ from mid 2009 or later, 15″ from late 2007 and newer, 17″ from late 2007 and newer
> - MacBook Air – late 2008 and newer
> - iMac – models from mid 2007 and newer
> - MacBook – 13″ aluminum from 2008, 13″ from 2009 and newer
> - Mac Mini – early 2009 and newer
> - Mac Pro – early 2008 models and newer
> - XServe – early 2009 models and newer

Source: http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/16/os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-system-requirements/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your hardware supports 10.8, and assuming Apple will use a similar distribution mechanism as they did for 10.7, you'll be able to obtain an installer that can be used even to install on a blank disk. For 10.7 it involves downloading the installer and extracting the InstallESD.dmg from inside it (right-click and choose "Show package contents"). You will need to do this from some other computer running at least 10.6.8 with the App Store.

In case a direct upgrade of 10.5 won't be supported by such an installer, you can simply use the Migration Assistant to copy your files and settings. If your system settings aren't crucial for you to save, you can save a lot of time by just deleting the system folders and the installing 10.8 on that disk - your documents folders should remain intact.

Comment: Apple has acknowledged that they will support a direct upgrade path to 10.8 from 10.6.8, but will not support direct from 10.5 to 10.7 or 10.8 without doing a backup and reinstall from scratch